# Chance of one of 4 numbers appearing at least once in 37 spins of roulette

Tags: probability

I have managed to find the probability of one number not appearing in 37 spins to be 0.362 and so the probability of the number appearing at least once is 1- 0.362 = 0.638

Just wandered how to calculate at least one of four numbers appearing at least once in 37 spins?

Comment: You seem to be using a roulette wheel with $37$ slots and calculated $\left(1- \frac1{37}\right)^{37} \approx 0.36285$.  Can you explain why you did that calculation and then consider how you might adjust it?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Okay thanks and I was using something more complicated that boils down to the same thing. I guess it's just a case of replacing the 1 with 4 that gives approximately

0.01450614

And so at least one of the four colours showing up once or more in 37 spins

1 - 0.014506144 ≈ 0.98549.

Comment: You are correct, but it would benefit future readers if you showed how you arrived at the first number.  This [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.  In this case, typing `$\left(1 - \frac{4}{37}\right)^{37} \approx 0.01450614$` yields $\left(1 - \frac{4}{37}\right)^{37} \approx 0.01450614$.  You can type `$$\left(1 - \frac{4}{37}\right)^37 \approx 0.01450614$$` to display the calculation on a separate line.